# Do anyone has solution for this hashmap question? I dont even know what it means

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public class HashMap 
{
//need to add some code here but I don't know what

    private class MyHashMap<K,V> {
        MyHashMap() {
        }
        void put(K key , V value) {
       // find solution
        }

        V get(K key) {
            //how to return value from key?
            return null;
        }
       // find solution
    }

    public void doTestsPass()
    {
        int [][] testCases = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{1,7},{1,8}};
        boolean passed = true;
        MyHashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new MyHashMap<>();

        for(int [] test: testCases){// find solution
            Integer key = test[0];
            Integer value = test[1];
            map.put(key,value);// find solution
            if(!value.equals(map.get(key))){
                System.out.println("Test failed["+key+","+value+"]"); 
                //need to find solution
                passed = false;
            }  
        }

        if(passed) {
            // find solution
            System.out.println("All tests passed");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] Args) { 
      // find solution
        new HashMap().doTestsPass();
    }
}
```

Comment: You doing a Java course?  It looks like you've been given an interface specification and need to write the implementation..  The naming suggests they're expecting you to implement a hash map, though you should know if that is actually required or if you can, in fact, provide any implementation that passes the tests.

Comment: yes doing java courses learning...yes i know i can provide any implementation but i also wanted to know this one....i studied all and looked everywhere but cannot find any for like this

Comment: Googling "implement hashmap in java" will get you working, but poor examples. Knuth's Art of Computer Programming is what you need to do this properly, but if you want to do the absolute minimum to get course credit, http://profesores.elo.utfsm.cl/~agv/elo320/PLDS210/niemann/s_has.htm seems to contain a good example.

Comment: ok thax bro for help ill check